# SQL query to convert the value to MM/DD/YY and HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql-server

My table `TRANS` contains `T_STAMP` column with the value '`20170721154922`' is a `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` format. I am trying to write a query to display as `MM/DD/YY` in one column and `HH:MM:SS` in another column.

I am trying to convert this with the method `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),10)`
but I need full snippet to execute.

Could you help .

Comment: Please use tag about involed DBMS. Maybe mysql is unuseful?

Comment: mysql != (MS)SQL-server

Comment: @Jens: I suppose right is sql-server  and not mysql. GETDATE() is sql-server

Comment: Storing timestamps as formated strings is no good idea. Better store it in a timestamp datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query can be return the exact format you required, the date as `MM/DD/YY` and time as `HH:MM:SS`:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(T_STAMP, 8)), 1) AS DateValue,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CONVERT(TIME, 
                      SUBSTRING(T_STAMP, 9, 2) + ':'
                    + SUBSTRING(T_STAMP, 11, 2) + ':'
                    + SUBSTRING(T_STAMP, 13, 2)), 8) AS TimeValue
FROM Trans
```

Output:

```
DateValue  | TimeValue
-----------|-----------
07/21/17   | 15:49:22
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE() , 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

the above would return something like this(21/07/2017 16:02:20).

Answer (score 1):

The following query will convert a value from the given format (`YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`) to `DATE` and `TIME`

```
DECLARE @T_STAMP NVARCHAR(100)='20170721154922'
SELECT  CONVERT(DATE,LEFT(@T_STAMP,8)) T_DATE
        ,CONVERT(TIME,SUBSTRING(@T_STAMP,9,2)+':'
                    +SUBSTRING(@T_STAMP,11,2)+':'
                    +SUBSTRING(@T_STAMP,13,2)) T_TIME
```

As you mentioned the values are stored in `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` format, so hope the values always be in fixed length (length 14).

**Note**:- As commented by Jens, Storing timestamps as formated strings is no good idea. Better store it in a timestamp datatype.

Answer (score 0):

```
select date_format(str_to_date('20170721154922', '%Y%m%d%H%S'), '%m%d%y');
```

Answer (score 0):

`'20170721154922'` is a very very bad format to store date...

```
DECLARE @d varchar(14) = '20170721154922';
DECLARE @date DATETIME = CONVERT(datetime2, LEFT(@d, 8), 112);
DECLARE @time DATETIME = CONVERT(datetime2, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@d, 9, 2), ':', SUBSTRING(@d, 11, 2), ':', SUBSTRING(@d, 13, 2)), 108);
SELECT FORMAT(@date, 'MM/dd/yy') date, FORMAT(@time, 'HH:mm:ss') time
```